# how to localhost saved values check using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to localhost saved values  check using java script,Button on click based  saving one  value,after page refresh  want to  check check value save,How to check

Comment: Cookies, sessionStorage come to mind.

Comment: no only using localhost storage only ,how to validate localhost values any value saved or not

Comment: Am I having difficulty understanding localhost save?

Comment: local storage of the browser

Comment: Right, this may be a good start: http://www.javablog.fr/html5web-client-storage-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage.html

Answer (score 0):

Dear you can use SESSION variable for it. You can store checked checkbox value in an index on array and that array stored in Session Variable. So by this way you will get all checked values and can use anywhere.

Comment: its possible but i want only localhost save based on condition using javascript

Comment: Dear than use cookies in javascript which work same like PHP sessions and you can store all inforamtion is javascript cookies.  here is simple explanation of javascript cookies which can help you.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

What is HTML5 Web Storage?
With HTML5, web pages can store data locally within the user's browser.

Earlier, this was done with cookies. However, Web Storage is more secure and faster. The data is not included with every server request, but used ONLY when asked for. It is also possible to store large amounts of data, without affecting the website's performance.

The data is stored in name/value pairs, and a web page can only access data stored by itself.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Example:

```
function getItem(key){
    if (!hasLocalStorage || !key) return;
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}

function setItem(key, val){
    if (!hasLocalStorage || !key) return;
    localStorage.setItem(key, val);
}

function hasLocalStorage () {
    return typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined';
}

//to store an item
setItem("itemKey", "itemVal");

//to retrieve an (the above, in this case) item
var fetchItem = getItem("itemKey");
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to store that value in cookies?